# Sigma algebra generated by a conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory

Given a probability space, a random variable $X$  and a sub sigma algebra $\mathcal G$. What is the sigma algebra generated by the conditional expectation $E (X\mid\mathcal G)$?

Is it the one generated by the intersection between the sigma algebra of $X$ and $\mathcal G$? Perhaps not.

It must be contained in $\mathcal G$, since $E (X\mid\mathcal G)$ is measurable wrt $\mathcal G$.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I changed $E(X|\mathcal{G})$ to $E(X\mid\mathcal{G})$, coded as E(X\mid\mathcal{G}).  They look different: $E(X|\mathcal{G})$ versus $E(X\mid\mathcal{G})$.  The latter is standard usage.

Comment: @Tim "contain" should be "be contained in"

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\cal H$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by ${\Bbb E} (X\mid\mathcal G)$.
As you say, since  ${\Bbb E} (X\mid\mathcal G)$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable, $\cal H$ is contained in $\mathcal G$.  It doesn't have to be contained in $\sigma(X)$.  For a simple counterexample, let the probability space be $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4\}$ with all subsets measurable and the uniform probability measure, and let $${\mathcal G}=\{\emptyset,\{1,2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{3,4\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\Omega\},$$ $$X(1)=1, X(2)=X(3)=X(4)=0.$$  Then 
$$
{\Bbb E} (X\mid\mathcal G)(1)={\Bbb E} (X\mid\mathcal G)(2)=\frac12,
\ \ \ \ 
{\Bbb E} (X\mid\mathcal G)(3)={\Bbb E} (X\mid\mathcal G)(4)=0$$
so ${\cal H}=\{\emptyset,\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\Omega\}$ is not contained in $\sigma(X)=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2,3,4\},\Omega\}$.

Since $\cal H$ does not have to be contained in $\sigma(X)$, it need not equal ${\cal G}\cap\sigma(X)$.  The example above shows that it also does not have to equal $\cal G$.

Addendum: As Byron Schmuland says below, if $X$ is an ${\cal F}/{\cal B}({\Bbb R})$-measurable real-valued function, then $\cal H$ is countably generated as it's the pullback of the countably generated $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal B}(\Bbb R)$ under ${\Bbb E} (X\mid\mathcal G)^ {-1}$.  Also, any countably generated $\sigma$-algebra which is contained in $\cal G$ can occur as a value of $\cal H$ for some real-valued $X$.  (${\Bbb E} (X\mid\mathcal G)$ is only defined up to equality on a set of measure $1$, so to be precise you should say that any countably generated $\sigma$-algebra which is contained in $\cal G$ can occur as a value of $\sigma({\Bbb E}(X\mid\mathcal G))$ for some real-valued $X$ and some version of ${\Bbb E}(X\mid \mathcal G)$.)

Comment: Thanks, can it be any subsigma algebra of $\mathcal G$?

Comment: @Tim The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathbb{E}(X\mid {\cal G})$, like any $\sigma$-algebra generated by a random variable, must be countably generated. So it cannot be *any* sub $\sigma$-algebra of ${\cal G}$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: it is countably generated, because a random variable takes value in $\mathbb R$ with the Borel sigma algebra?

Comment: @Tim Yes, that is right.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what E(E(X | G)) would be?

Comment: ${\Bbb E}({\Bbb E} (X\mid\mathcal G))={\Bbb E}(X).$