# Remove one sigma algebra from another?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose we have a sigma algebra $\sigma_Y$ and another $\sigma_X\subset \sigma_Y$.

I know how to "add" sigma algebra's together (take the join), and how to find their intersection (take the meet).

But is there a way to "remove $\sigma_X$ from $\sigma_Y$"? Intuitively, this would be the equivalent for sigma algebras of what $A\backslash B$ is for sets, i.e. $A\cap B^c$. Another intuition is: in probability theory, a sigma algebra $\sigma_X$ represents "the information in the variable $X$". We might be interested in "the information contained in the variable $Y$ that is not also contained in $X$", and write it as $$\sigma_Y\backslash \sigma_X$$

Is there a meaningful definition for this that captures the above intuitions? The straightforward definition doesn't work, which is to interpret $\backslash$ set-theoretically, and then take the closure.

Comment: This is not really an answer, but from a probabilistic interpretation we know that the information in $Y$ that is not controlled by $X$ is captured in the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]$. So you might look at the $\sigma$-algebra generated by that conditional expectation, $\sigma(\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X])$. It's been discussed: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318706/sigma-algebra-generated-by-a-conditional-expectation. I'd be interested to hear if this interpretation leads anywhere for you.

Comment: @cwindolf, it seems to me that the conditional expectation loses a lot of information, since you lose the distribution of $Y$ conditional on $X$ and only get a single value from it.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking about it, and I had it backwards -- better to look at $\sigma(\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y])$, since that is $\sigma_Y$-measurable and certainly $\sigma_Y\setminus\sigma_X$ should be too. Maybe this captures the idea better?

Comment: @cwinfolf, it seems like you still can lose a lot of information in that case, just because the distribution of $X$ may *happen* to induce the same expected value for two values of $Y$, even if the conditional distributions of $X$ given those values dont even have overlapping support.

Comment: Totally agree. But maybe if your goal is to $\setminus \sigma_X$ you have to lose some of your sensitivity to $Y$ as well, at least when they are not independent? But anyway, I think you are maybe looking for something more constructive or based in set operations, and this is probably not that.